# hint_text stays blank when added from python

Tags: python, kivy

```
AddEm = MDTextField(hint_text=f"Hello 1"


                             )
        self.MainLayout.ids[f'text_inputs'].add_widget(AddEm
        )
```

I have this. If I run it as is, I don't get any hint text, just blank. But if I do `text=f"Hello 1"` then it works and adds the text. Other properties of MDTextField work too. Also, if I add the `hint_text=f"Hello 1"` directly in the kv file, it also works and shows the hint correctly.

Comment: instead of using the MDTextField, try doing it with TextInput - see if it works

Comment: It works with TextInput. The issue seems to be kivymd only.